# Deleting multiple identically named files each in separate folder

Tags: visual-studio-code

I work on rather big ( 800+ files ) project in VSCode and got somewhat stuck today.

There are multiple files **with exact same name** in multiple folders. Deleting each one manually is painstaking.

These files are: `en.yml` and `fr.yml`

I know I can `Find & Replace`, it finds all occurrences of files I want to delete all `en.yml` and `fr.yml` files.

Is there an easy way of automating / achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best to do it from the terminal/shell

```
find . -name en.yml | xargs -I {} rm {}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Many thanks